# Smooth fly movements like flappy bird --> isFlapping Boolean?

Tags: android, game-physics

I know there is a similar question: [Smooth fly movement like flappy bird or jet pack joy ride with gravity and Accelaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442495/smooth-fly-movement-like-flappy-bird-or-jet-pack-joy-ride-with-gravity-and-accel)

But I don't understand how to check if isFlapping is true and to use this information to start the flight of the bird...

Because here:

```
dY += gravity + flapping;
y += dY;
bird.setY(y);
```

the flapping action will be used all the time but not only when the user touches the screen.
Please help

Comment: is flapping is true when user taps the screen, right? then make it false after x amount of time.

Comment: Yes, but how can I check the boolean before + flapping, because I tried to leave that out and to add the flapping int on clicking the screen, but then the fly effect doesn't work...

Comment: what ide are you using?

Comment: I use Android Studio

Comment: ok. so if you click of having a "fly" button. tap it, were flying. tap it, disable for half a second or so... then another half second bird drops. or whatever your logic is. the button is how you know its flapping really. you have a global variable thats true/false. if its done in unity, it would actually be a lot easier.